# Limit displayed text length (from DB) in PHP?

Tags: php, html, sql

I am able to load data off my database into my webpage. However, there are a couple of instances where I would like to limit the number of characters that are placed on a row.

For example, "DESCRIPTION" is a varchar(200), and I only want to show the first 30 characters on this particular page.

```
<td><?php print $row->DESCRIPTION; ?></td>
```

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks.

Ended up using this,

```
<td><?php print substr($row->DESCRIPTION,0,20); ?></td>
```

Comment: Seriously, a close vote as "too localized"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it on the php side with `substr`.

```
<?php echo substr($row->DESCRIPTION, 30); ?>
```

Of course that doesnt take into account words and what not so you might need to get more complex with that by writing a custom function if thats important.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about substr

Comment: +1. Just to note that MySQL has a `substr` function too: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substr but doing it on the PHP side seems like the cleaner solution

Answer (score 0):

you could also adapt the mysql query

```
SELECT SUBSTR(DESCRIPTION,1,5)
FROM Table
WHERE value = 'Denver';
```